# How do I check balance on my offline wallet while I did not assign any transaction ID?

Tags: mnemonic-seed

I generated adresses at moneroaddress.org and sent to them my funds from Poloniex. I have installed Monero Gui Beta 1 and when I import wallets with seed frases I see no funds at all. How do I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the GUI, and restoring from seed you'll need to scan the blockchain from scratch to find your deposited coins. This is a time consuming process so you'll need to be patient and ideally do it with your own node if you want to preserve your privacy, or make the process faster. If you know the blockheight of the first deposit you can save yourself a lot of time by inputting the blockheight when you restore from seed.

Until you've scanned the blockchain you'll not know your balance, but it only needs to be done once as the wallet will progressively check the blockchain as new blocks come in. If you haven't specified remote node, or don't have a local node to connect to this will never happen though. It requires to make sure you have one of these things in order to scan the blockchain.

Comment: Everything was synced but the thingy I omitted was to click the link in the email with withdrawal confirmation so in reality the addresses I delivered to Poloniex were empty(Poloniex was awaiting the confirmation). Once I clicked those links everything poped up in place.